# Determining a Generic Type at Runtime in Non-Generic Class

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, reflection

I've gotten myself in a pickle, and could use the help of a guru...

I have a Journal that records entries for different types:

```
Journal(Of ParentT)
```

- Parent could be `Customer`, `Address`, other classes

The constructor of the Journal requires knowledge of the Type parameter:

```
Public Sub New(Parent as ParentT)
```

In my consuming form, I take a Journal in the constructor:

```
Public Sub DisplayForm(Journal as object)
```

At this point, I cannot determine what type the Journal is for. I have looked at using Reflection with the `MethodInfo` > `MakeGenericMethod`, `DynamicMethod`, delegates, etc, but haven't found a workable solution.

I am willing to consider most any option at this point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood the question, but if I understand correctly, `Journal` is in fact a generic class with generic parameter `ParentT`; it is only that the reference to a `Journal<ParentT>` instance is of the non-generic `System.Object` type. In this case, the following method should work fine:

[`System.Type.GetGenericArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx)

Sorry that this code is in C#, but:

```
 object obj = new List<int>();
 Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First().ToString());
```

Output:

```
System.Int32
```

In your case, you might want something like:

```
Type journalGenericType = myJournal.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First();

if (journalGenericType == typeof(Customer))
{
    ...
}
else 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wow - I spent hours looking for this! Thanks.

Comment: @grefly: Great. Are you sure you can't change the design to not require reflection though?

Comment: I have to make a decision in IoC based on type of Journal - (I did *not* favor Convention over Configuration!) - so what would that design change look like? I am open to suggestions/recommendataions...

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to this party, but I thought I'd weigh in.

There are a number of non-reflection-based approached you could use here.

This `DisplayMethod` call that you pass the journal to isn't the constructor of your form (otherwise it'd be called `New`) so I assume that it is a method that figures out which form to load to display the journal.

If so, you could simply add the generic parameter to this method call like so:

```
Public Sub DisplayForm(Of ParentT)(Journal As Journal(Of ParentT))
   Dim JournalParentType = GetType(ParentT)
   '...
End Sub
```

Since you're using IoC you could even go one step further. Something like this:

```
Public Sub DisplayForm(Of ParentT)(Journal As Journal(Of ParentT))
   Dim form = ioc.Resolve(Of IForm(Of ParentT))
   form.DataSource = Journal.Parent
   form.Show()
End Sub
```

Of course you would need to define your own `IForm(Of T)` interface to make this work - but now there is no reflection required.

Another approach would be to have a `Journal` base class of `Journal(Of ParentT)` and have a `ParentType` property on Journal. Alternatively you could have an `IJournal` interface that does the same thing.